# iOS 403 App attestation failed but Android is fine?

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-app-check, devicecheck

I just cannot get App Check to work with iOS. My config is fine with Android. I have created a key and used it to configure DeviceCheck. I am testing on a physical device (iPhone 6s). Running in debug mode I get the following when my app tries to wtite to Firestore:

```
9.4.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] AppCheck failed: 'The operation couldn’t be completed. The server responded with an error: 
 - URL: https://firebaseappcheck.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my_project/apps/1:407394906485:ios:5094cebb0136b1f8ac233c:exchangeDebugToken 
 - HTTP status code: 403 
 - Response body: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "App attestation failed.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I feel like I've tried everything. Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I also have same issue since some days ago, but I've solved this issue.
In my case of the reason was debug token mismatched.
Therefore I think it need to add debug token on firebase console every iOS app installed.
Because 'app check' will regenerate debug token when install iOS app.
Or you should try to update firebase packages to latest.

I hope this answer to your helpful.